# JQuery: multiple rollovers

Tags: jquery, rollover

I have multiple DIVs containing an image in each. When I rollover these DIVs, I want another DIV to fade in over the top. When I roll off this new DIV, it should fade out again. Essentially I want something like the grid of thumbnails here http://www.visualboxsite.com/

This is the code I have written:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $("div.projectImage").mouseenter(function () {
      $("div.textRollover").fadeIn(100);
    });

    $("div.textRollover").mouseleave(function () {
      $("div.textRollover").fadeOut(100);
    });

  }); 
</script>
```

The problems with this are:

- When I roll over one of the DIVs, ALL of the new DIVs appear, not just the one I have the mouse over
- Moving the mouse over and off the DIVs repeatedly 'stack' the fade in/fade out functions

Can anyone help fix these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be more specific than just calling any div with that classname, or you'll match too much (as you discovered). In the following code, we only match the child element that has that classname:

```
$(".rollMe").hover(
  function(){
    /* 'this' is whichever div.rollMe you are currently
       hovering over at this particular moment */
    $(this).find("div.iFade").fadeIn(100);
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find("div.iFade").fadeOut(100);
  }
);

<div class="rollMe">
  <div class="iFade">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't quite work. When I roll over one of the thumbnails, they still all fade in. Only now, when I roll off, just the one you're rolling off fades out.

Comment: That's interesting - it works fine when I create a limited test case. I will slowly add more elements from my site and see what's causing it.

Here's the test case - you'll see repeatedly moving the mouse over and off 'stacks' the effects - is there a way around this? http://www.joesmalley.com/temp/jquery-rollover-test.html

Comment: Got to the bottom of the first problem - I didn't have the jQuery code in the <head> tag

Comment: @Joe, that would cause some problems :) Well, you can insert the script into the bottom of the body - Yahoo even suggests this for high-traffic websites.